# Can't get JSONAPI relationships to populate ember-data for the nested models

Tags: ember-data

I am trying to get nested relationships work for my api but no success so far. Every "report" can have multiple "nodes".
Here are my models:

```js
//model report.js

export default DS.Model.extend({
  // == Relationships =========================================================
  nodes: hasMany('node', {async: false})// to check this inverse: null
})
```

```js
//model node.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  changeType: attr('string'),
  report: belongsTo('report')
})
```

here is my serializer for report.js

```js
// serializer for report.js
export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  keyForAttribute: function (attr) {
    return attr
  },
  keyForRelationship: function (key) {
    return key
  },

  normalizeResponse: function (store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
    return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, this.getNewPayload(payload), id, requestType)
  },

  getNewPayload (payload) {
    let newPayload = {
      data: []
    }
    if (!isNone(payload)) {
      let nodeId = 1
      if (payload.data instanceof Array) {
        let nodeRelationship = []
        let included = []
        payload.data.map((record) => {
          nodeRelationship.pushObject({id: nodeId, type: 'node'})
          included.pushObject({id: nodeId, type: 'node', attributes: record.node}) // attributes: record.node
          nodeId++
        })
        newPayload.data.push({
          id: 0,
          type: 'report',
          attributes: {},
          relationships: {
            nodes: {
              data: nodeRelationship
            }
          },
          included: included
        })
      }
    }
    return newPayload
  }

})
```

here is how my data looks like.

```js
export default {
  "data": [
    {
      "node": {
        "changeType": "added",
        "name": "node1"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "changeType": "removed",
        "name": "nodel2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong here when i inspect ember-data, node model is empty. I appreciate any help

Comment: Your api response seems strange to me. It's not including any id. You are generating them on the fly in serializer. Also you are creating a record for another entity (`report`) in the serializer. I would expect several issue with that down the road. E.g. how would your API know which record should be updated or deleted on accordingly requests? Could you please include some more insights on this strange data format?